# Automapper and multidimensional list

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I want to map `List<List<Item>>` into `List<List<Item2>>` but I can't make it working. Is there a way to do it using simple configuration or does such case require writing custom converter? Here is my case (available also on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B16CaF)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ItemCollection, List<List<Item2>>>();
            cfg.CreateMap<List<List<Item>>, List<List<Item2>>>();
            cfg.CreateMap<List<Item>, List<Item2>>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Item, Item2>().ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Name));
        });
        var mapper = new Mapper(configuration);
        
        var collection = new ItemCollection();
        collection.Add(new List<Item>(){new Item{Name = "item"}});
        
        var dest = mapper.Map<List<List<Item2>>>(collection);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dest));
    }
}

public class ItemCollection : List<List<Item>>
{
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Item2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As a result I'd like to see `[[{Name = "item"}]]` in output window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to specify how to map to collections, only the individual types.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/D6HGik

Comment: stupid me... thanks